# How can I make a test bench for an electric motor?

Tags: motor, testing

I'm in college and we are designing a plane for SAE Aero Design, we are trying to come up with a design for a litle test bench for our motor any idea how can we do it, a DIY way, also do you guys have any advice for us?

Comment: First you need some idea of the loads : weight, torque, vibration, thrust etc.

Comment: Welcome, stack exchange sites are reserved only for specific questions which can have specific answers, and that's not what you have posted.  Your need is rather the sort where you should **do some web searching to see the range of ideas used by those with similar needs**.  In particular you'll find that RC hobbyists on places like rcgroups have from time to time built rigs for benchmarking various motors.  You'll probably also find writeups in various student thesis.

Comment: The easiest setup would be a Prony brake, a weighing scale and RPM meter.

Comment: Look for a suitable motor dynamometer. Choose one sized adequately for your torque / HP. Program it to model your load, done.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is to use a second identical motor, directly coupled to it, as a generator. Then the generator is loaded with resistors for braking.

Often the motors will have symmetrical mounting holes, which allows the two bodies to be connected to each other with standoffs. If the motors are simply cylindrical, then I use two or three sections of angle, arranged round the two motors with strong elastic bands or tube clamps.

Comment: My only problem with this answer is that the OP is "designing a plane" (with, so far, no further details).  I've seen half megawatt electric motors for that purpose, at which point angle iron and elastic bands probably won't cut it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You haven't seen my elastic bands! They weigh 500 g, and were intended to store 2 kJ to power a fighting robot's hammer.